# Can I store a variable array of strings inside application settings file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to store a list of 10-20 elements inside application configuration file in a C# application. I realize that I can use add key tags in appsettings section, but then I will have to create a unique key for each.

I am planning to loop over the elements in a section, and tried storing it. but it fails it initialize confiuration managager

EDIT: I want to store a section for table names to verify , where user can enter a list of tables to run a test on each

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx).

- [MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228056.aspx)
- [Code Project Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/namevaluemultiple.aspx) (This directly references multiple values, and may be more helpful with what you're going for)

**EDIT**

Just as an aside, this may be more work that you need given your last edit. You could just use a delimiter [not found in the acceptable identifier list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) and split the string. (probably a whole lot easier)

Comment: Yup, create your own ConfigurationSection classes, handle it yourself. Not hard to do.